# How to send html tags from view to controller in codeigniter using ajax with json datatype?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I need to send a value from textarea with html tags and inline css codes. I used ajax to do       this with json as a datatype. The problem is it does not return the exact html tags and styling.

```
 $('#add_course_form').submit(function(e) {


 var course_desc=tinymce.get('course_desc').getContent();

  $.ajax({
     url         :"<?php echo base_url();?>courses/upload_file/",
     dataType    : 'json',
     data        : {


   **'course_desc'     :course_desc,**

                   },
     success  : function (data, status)
     {
       if(data.status != 'error')
        {
         $("#alert_register").fadeIn(100);
         $("#alert_register").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
         setTimeout('delayer()', 11000);
        }

     }

  });
```

The course_desc contains this kind of code:

```
<p style="text-align:center">BSIT</p>
```

And I used the code below in my controller to get the value of the course_desc:

```
$this->input->post('course_desc');
```

The result it returns is `<p style=`

Answer (score 0):

In your `data` section you have

```
data : {
   **'course_desc'     :course_desc,**    
       }
```

That will send the following to the server (assuming ** is markdown)

```
course_desc=<p style="text-align:center">BSIT</p>
```

That's not valid JSON so you need to change it to

```
{course_desc:'<p style="text-align:center">BSIT</p>'}
```

Note that the `dataType` in your code is the expected Return type not the type you are sending.

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server (jQuery docs)